# integrate net banking and debit card payment gateway to indian shopping site

Tags: payment-methods

We are devoloping shopping site for indian customers.

So we have to integrate "online banking payment gateway" & "debit card" that should include all the banks

in india. please guide me to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to find a payment service provider that suits your needs. It's impossible to integrate every bank but a Payment Service Provider generally offers a wide range of banks and cards to connect to after integrating their plugin.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_payment_service_providers

Comment: thanks a lot for reply. 

as you are from netherland, I can't ask you, which is the best online payment service providers in india.
This is for some indian devolopers who reads the comment....

thanks again....

Comment: ask theme for uptime statistics, that's an important aspect. Generally, if the offer a lot of legit payment methods they tend to be pretty ok but indeed, this is from what I know of dutch psp's :)

Comment: I assume you want  to me ask for theme devolopers for integration. am i right?

Comment: Theme developers? There is a big chance they offer a ready to go Magento module

Comment: is by default magento go have payent set up?  i heard magento will close "magento go"

in few months.

Comment: paypal payment method is more than enough to perform any type of transaction in any country BTW I belong to INDIA and I use paypal to get all the payment options say Netbanking,Credit,Debit card payments.

Comment: @dh47 please add your comment as answer. It is valuable information

Comment: @BabyinMagento, have you got the solution for your question? I am also trying to get this.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara before we had plan like this. later we decided to tie up with multiple payment gateway teams. so we tied up with payu, ccavenue & hdfc.

Comment: @BabyinMagento. ok. but i have to use this payment method on my website. Client require that. Do you know the solution for this?

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara are you telling you have to integrate payment team extensions or you want to integrate direct net banking, credit card as payment method ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento, through netbanking and through debit card also.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara as Sander suggested in answer, i think its very difficult to integrate for every bank. if possible please convince the client.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara for my knowledge only flipkart, amazon, snapdeal kind of sites will do this.

Answer (score 2):

**Paypal Payment Method**
paypal payment method is more than enough to perform any type of transaction in any country BTW I belong to INDIA and I use paypal to get all the payment options say Netbanking,Credit,Debit card payments.

Comment: Hi dh47,

Thanks a lot for reply.

Are you using Normal "Paypal Payment Method", which is integrated with magento.

or Are you using any extension? 

IS it possible to pay using "Net banking through paypal"

please guide me.

Comment: Yea I'm sure Paypal will be enough for every Payment method  just know how to use paypal at present i'm litte busy with some project surely I will help later in the evening maybe untill them please go through google.

Answer (score 0):

**Razorpay Payment Method** is best in India. You can use and configure it very easily.

You will get all payment options like **Cards, UPI/QR, Netbanking, Wallets, Pay later, etc** in a single payment method.

You can install the Razorpay module for free. https://github.com/razorpay/razorpay-magento/

I personally used this.